# iOS MapKit - How to use custom textures?

Tags: ios, swift, mapkit

Currently I'm using the **iOS default Map** :

[image: image 1]

---

But how cool would it be to edit all textures of (streets / rivers / train-trails, ...)?

Would it be possible to achieve something like this?

- Changing maybe just the **color of water** **from default-blue** to **red**?
- Changing maybe just the **texture of the default compass** to a **cool new one**?
- Changing the **user-location indicator** to a **much cooler symbol**??

---

Is this possible to achieve something like this using Swift? All I found so far was Apples `MKTileOverlay` but I don't think this is the right way to start.

Help would be very appreciated, thanks in advance.